# using awk in tcl script

Tags: regex, awk, tcl

I want to print a particular column number fields in a file while in TCL script.

I tried with `exec awk '{print $4}' foo` where foo is filename, but it is not working as it gives error

`can't read "4": no such variable`

How can I do above awk in tcl scripting?

Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that single quotes have no special meaning in Tcl, they're just ordinary characters in a string. Thus the `$4` is not hidden from Tcl and it tries to expand the variable.

The Tcl equivalent to shell single quotes are braces. This is what you need:

```
exec awk {{print $4}} foo
```

The double braces look funny, but the outer pair are for Tcl and the inner pair are for awk.

Btw, the Tcl translation of that awk program is:

```
set fid [open foo r]
while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
    set fields [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line]
    puts [lindex $fields 3]
}
close $fid
```

Comment: Perfect answer. `Awk` is perfectly usable from Tcl, as is `sed` — and sometimes that's the easiest way to do things — but you have to remember that Tcl's syntax is not the same as that of a normal Unix shell. Why does Tcl use braces instead of single quotes? Because they're trivially nestable.

Comment: % exec [cat log.file | awk {{print $1}}]
can't read "1": no such variable
while evaluating {exec [cat log.file | awk {{print $1}}]}

Doesn't seem to work for me, am I doing something stupid? Or is there a caveat to the answer?

Comment: I'm using tcl 8.4.5 in case that is of relevance.

Comment: This does work, so I am guessing the square braces are trying to evaluate the variable. 

% exec head log.file | awk {{print $1}}

Jun
Jun
Jun
Jun
Jun
Jun
Jun
Jun
Jun